# How to achieve infrared and visible image registration, and finally make the two image scenes exactly the same

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Now I have detailed internal parameters and images taken by the infrared camera and the visible camera, but I am not sure whether the external parameters are accurate. The resolution of the infrared image is (640,480), and the resolution of the visible image is (2460,1920). How can you change the scene of the visible image into the same as the infrared image?

[image]

[image]

We have tried to calculate the homography matrix through the camera parameters to transform the visible light, but the result is not ideal, and the result of the same scene cannot be achieved.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have a look a perspective image warping. Images wont be perfectly the same (that's technically not possible after 2D projection from different positions) be they will be nearly the same.

Comment: Please post what y ou have tried so far to solve your question. Additionally, an image of desirable results might apply here as well.

Comment: This is actually a mechanical probem, you first have to place both cameras to face the same direction with same angle of view. Than it won't be a perfect match one image will have a wider range you should crop the wider image make the best possible fit. Again it wont be a perfect fit since the images depend on the internal parameters of the cameras.

Comment: Lop off the right amount off the left hand side and bottom of the visible image and the corresponding amount off the right hand side of the thermal image. Those differences are due to parallax since the lenses are taking slightly different shots in infrared and visible. A better visible light exposure or histogram equalisation would help to match features more accurately. Foreground is always going to be a bit tricky unless there are nice sharp vertical features to latch onto. It also was necessary to rescale the IR image by x1.2 in the y direction since the shed roof doesn't match otherwise.